# ReceivedTime of the mail is not showing in python

Tags: python, windows, outlook, pywin32, mapi

I am trying to read my mail and see the received time in outlook 2016 using MAPI. 
I am able to see the subject of the mail not able to see the ***receivedTime*** of the mail. I know that "Receivedtime" is there to get the received time of the mail, but while the program is executed,
**a popup is coming, telling that python has stopped working**

I know it is not due to any machine problem rather some problem in my code.

Here is my code.

```
def arrange(mailbox):
    global spam
    timeperiod() # stores required date in spam[] list
    msgs=mailbox.Items
    msgs.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
    p=msgs.restrict(" [ReceivedTime] >= '"+spam[2]+"'") #and [ReceivedTime] >= '" +spam[1]+"'    
    print(len(p))

    '''
    for m in list1:
        if m.Unread:
            m.Unread=False
            '''
    return p

#Calling it
ctm1=arrange(ctm)

print(len(ctm1)) #Working fine
for message in ctm1:
    print (message.subject) #Also works good
    print (message.receivedTime) # Here is the problem, it's not showing
```

[image: screenshot]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfrZ7.png)

**i have tried Senton property as well, but it's not working . So any guesses why the senton or receivedTime  properties are not working???**

updated code :

```
def printlist(box1) :
print(len(box1))

for message in box1:
    if message.Class==43 :
      #  print('true')
        print (message)
        #.senderEmailAddress) #working
        #print(message.SentOn.strftime("%d-%m-%y")) #not working
        #print(message.body)
        #print(message.UnRead)
        #print (message.receivedTime) #not working
#print('-----------')
```

Comment: Are you learning python? Please format your code properly

Comment: What's `mailbox`? This doesn't look like a standard IMAP or POP3 library.

Comment: @MikeScotty, that was a typo, i have edited now.

Comment: @bigbounty, yes i am. i have formatted now.

Comment: @tripleee, i am using the IMAP on outlook 2016.

Comment: My question pertains to which Python library you are using to do that. These methods are not available in the standard library and googling didn't bring up any other good candidates. We can't debug code for which there is no way to find documentation.

Comment: Your code still has obvious indentation errors. Some lines after `def` need to be indented but we cannot guess which ones. On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, select the pasted block, and type ctrl-K to have it properly formatted as code, with indents preserved.

Comment: @tripleee, i am using win32com.client to open outlook and then getting the namespace using MAPI. Then i am getting the inbox or particular folder, trying to restrict the mails between a particular period. Now i am getting the mails, but not getting the receivedtime or any subject/body property.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to clarify this too. Please review the speculative indentation edit, too. MAPI is not IMAP.

Comment: @tripleee, i have editd the code and also added the MAPI . please provide an answer

Answer (score 1):

I was also having trouble with the .ReceivedTime breaking the program when I compile the .py script to an .exe using auto-py-to-exe.

Here's where the error occurs underneath this try: statement

```
    try:
        received_year = str(email.ReceivedTime)[0:4]
        received_month = str(email.ReceivedTime)[5:7]
        received_day = str(email.ReceivedTime)[8:10]
```

This works PERFECTLY well inside of my IDE (PyCharm), but once I've compiled it to .exe, it breaks here.

I've updated pywin32 to the most up-to-date version (228) and also tried using 224 to see if it was a version issue (it wasn't).

BUT!! Going through this, I FOUND THE BUG! When you compile to .exe with auto-py-to-exe, it does not include the package "win32timezone" which the .ReceivedTime portion needs to run correctly. So you need to import this package for it to work.

All you have to do to fix this is include this at the top of your .py script before compiling to .exe:
import win32timezone

Let me know if this works for anyone else facing this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you run into an item other than `MailItem` - you can also have `ReportItem` and `MeetingItem` objects in your Inbox; none of them expose the `ReceivedTime` property.

Check that `message.Class` property == 43 (`olMail`) before accessing any other MailItem specific properties.

Comment: Because Subject property is exposed by all 3 object types.

Comment: How to check that 43 condition ?? Like on any particular mail??

Comment: if message.Class == 43: <the rest of your message code>

Comment: its showing true as i compared with the condition. Still not able to print the received time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:
print([x.ReceivedTime for x in messages])